# How to call all event handlers concurrently bind to an event

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, task-parallel-library

Couple of days ago I faced a question that How to call all the Event handler bind to an event in parallel.

My questions are:

1. how to get the list of all the event handler bound to an event?
2. while I would be calling all the event handlers, no one should be able to add a new event handler to that event. So, basically I need to acquire lock while I am calling event handler. So, how to address this issue in c#?

Answer (score 2):

1. To get the list of all listeners bound to an event, use `GetInvocationList`
2. Since delegates are immutable, all you have to do is grab a reference to the delegate itself. If someone adds a listener to the shared event, a new one will be created - and the one you're iterating over will remain unchanged. No locks required.

```
EventHandler handler = OnEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(handler.GetInvocationList(),
        del => del.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean getting the invocation list?

```
var handler = MyHandler;
if (handler != null)
{
    var invocationList = handler.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (EventHandler receiver in invocationList)
        receiver.BeginInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty, null, null);
}
```

you can simply lock the invocation by using a `lock(_myLock)` statement around that codeblock.